# socket.io/socket.io.js cannot be found

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have this socket server:

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

...

app.listen(3001);
```

Express and socket versions:

```
"express": "^4.16.3",
"socket.io": "^2.1.1"
```

And I call this on client side:

```
<script src="http://localhost:3001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

When I run socket server and open client app on chrome, I get this message: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

I don't intent to copy socket.io.js to a public folder as it's not the right way to do it according to socket.io docs.

That said, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Possible fixes:

- Make sure you run `npm install` and you don't have errors or incomplete installations:
- inside your project's directory, go to `./node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist` and copy the file named `socket.io.js` and put it into one of your `static` or `resources` directory.

Don't forget put the following line to serve static files, now you should be able to browse it under: http://localhost:3000/resources/socket.io/socket.io.js

```
 app.use('/resources', express.static('resources'));
```

If not fixed, here is a complete basic example follow the steps below.

Copy paste the following into a file `myfile.js`

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);




http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Run the following commands:

```
$ npm i express --save 
$ npm i socket.io --save 
$ node myfile.js
```

Open your browser http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js

Comment: I already did everything you said (and didn't work) except installing socketio package once socket.io documentation explicitly says to use "npm install --save socket.io" as you can see on https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: so did it work now after `npm install socketio --save`!

Comment: here is a fix where you manually copy the `socket.io.js ` file from `node_modules` into your static directory/folder. check my updated answer

Comment: This is not the correct answer either. As I said: “I don’t intent to copy socket.io.js to a public folder as it’s not the right way to do it according to socket.io docs.”